# ServletContextListener with Timer is not showing output in console

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, netbeans, timer

I have made basic web app where i have taken one POJO class which extends the TimerTask and a servlet class which implements the ServletContextListener.Now my concern is i want to show the output on every 1 minute on console as i have given that in timer set..but i am not able to see any output..

Also my concern is as i have only one servlet and one pojo file without main method then how to run this appication .I am using Netbeans ide..

Here is my servlet code..

```
public class MyContext implements ServletContextListener {

private ScheduledExecutorService sched;

@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
    sched = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    sched.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MyTask(), 0, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
}

@Override
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
    sched.shutdownNow();
}
```

}

And here is my POJO class code..

```
class MyTask extends TimerTask {

public void run() {
    // your code here

    System.out.println("Timer Started");
}
```

}

Please help me to be out of this situation..
Thanks in advance

Comment: How can this happen there is  no linking between your context and pojo?Why dont you write times in context initialized?

Comment: @constantlearner here i am calling POJO new MyTask() in the servlet code please see

Answer (score 0):

You need to annotated `MyContext` class with `@WebListener()`

```
@WebListener()
public class MyContext implements ServletContextListener {

 ......
}
```

Comment: i updated my code with urs and ran my web app still i am not seeing anything as output on console

Comment: To make it faster use TimeUnit.SECONDS than test.

Comment: in my app i have one servlet and one java file only and i am using netbeans ..i am running my by right clicking and selcting run in netbeans

Comment: To run ServletContextListener you don't need Servlet. It will call on deployment.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40942/discussion-between-adi-and-masud)